# emacsclient single executions are expensive?

Tags: emacsclient

I have `server-mode` enabled so that I can use `emacsclient` to execute functions from other parts of my system. My main example is that I have a polybar module that calls `emacsclient` for some details about the active Emacs frame. When polybar is periodically calling `emacsclient`, I've noticed that the server uses up more CPU, seemingly in pursuit of deleting each new client. This makes editing feel a bit slower.

Here is a CPU sample of me editing a file.

[image]

How can I execute some elisp in the Emacs server environment without creating a whole new client each time (by calling `emacsclient`)?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the source code of `emacsclient` to reimplement it in your preferred programming language and using that to make a persistent process that sends requests to Emacs without establishing a new connection every time.

Comment: What's the question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: These calls seem to add significant overhead to editing, so I was wondering if there's a way to execute some elisp in the Emacs server environment without creating a whole new client each time.

Comment: Then ask that question in your question, please: "How do I...?"